# How to replace characters in a string and convert to double?

Tags: java

The 2 dimensional array is purely reference as of now. I need to know how to replace characters in a string with corresponding integers and display it in double format.

For example, according to `conversionTable` ---> `[Input: "ab.a" , Output: "1.0"]` OR `[Input: "a.jjj" , Output: "0.999"]`. I attempt to achieve this thru switch-case but it gives error. How can i achieve this thru switch case OR even more efficiently?

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Double;
public class Decrypt {

private static String conversionTable[][] = {
        {"a", "0"},
        {"b", "1"},
        {"c", "2"},
        {"d", "3"},
        {"e", "4"},
        {"f", "5"},
        {"g", "6"},
        {"h", "7"},
        {"i", "8"},
        {"j", "9"},
};

public static double decrypt(String encryptedNumber) {

String input = encryptedNumber;

switch(input.length()){

case 'a':
System.out.print(input.replace('a', '0'));
break;

case 'b':
System.out.print(input.replace('b','1'));
break;

case 'c':
System.out.print(input.replace('c', '2'));
break;

case 'd':
System.out.print(input.replace('d','3'));
break;

case 'e':
System.out.print(input.replace('e','4'));
break;

case 'f':
System.out.print(input.replace('f','5'));
break;

case 'g':
System.out.print(input.replace('g','6'));
break;

case 'h':
System.out.print(input.replace('h','7'));
break;

case 'i':
System.out.print(input.replace('i','8'));
break;

case 'j':
System.out.print(input.replace('j','9'));
break;
}


 Double d = new Double(""); 
 double result = Double.parseDouble(input);
 return result;


}

public static void main(String arg[]){

Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the string to decrypt:");
String input=scanner.next();
System.out.println("Number after decryption is:"+decrypt(input));

}  

}
```

Comment: "but it gives an error." What error do you receive? A full stack trace is preferred, as we can see exactly *what* the error is and *where* it occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something with `(char) ('0' + (ch - 'a'))` because we know that 'a' is 'a', and 'b' - 'a' should be '1'. For example,

```
private static String decryptString(String en) {
  if (en == null) {
    return "";
  }
  en = en.trim().toLowerCase();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (char ch : en.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'j') {
      sb.append((char) ('0' + (ch - 'a')));
    } else {
      sb.append(ch);
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static Double decrypt(String encryptedNumber) {
  return Double.valueOf(decryptString(encryptedNumber));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(decrypt("ab.a"));
  System.out.println(decrypt("a.jjj"));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
1.0
0.999
```

Comment: perfect, can you explain the logic behind (char)(0+(ch-a) further though? Why are we essentially adding and subtracting zero?

Comment: Not `0`, it's `'0'` which is the ascii character '0'. If you look at the ascii character table, you'll see that 'b' is one past 'a', which is one less then 'c' and so forth. Anyway, when cast to `int` '0' is 48 and 'a' is 97.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a very ugly one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] index = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"};

    String str= "ab.a";
    String strNew = str;
    for(int i=0;i<index.length;i++){
        strNew = strNew.replaceAll(index[i], String.valueOf(i));
    }

    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(strNew));
}
```

Comment: May be we need to think about the lower case and upper case, never mind, just switch to lower case before decryption.